# Importing QtGui from pyqtgraph.Qt as *

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyside, pyqtgraph

I am trying to insert a graph in my PySide GUI using `pyqtgraph`.

**Objective:** keep using wildcard imports for PySide while obeying `pyqtgraph`s import rules.

Apparently, `PySide.QtCore` and `PySide.QtGui` needs to be imported through `pyqtgraph` for the package to work properly. In the example, its written like this:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
```

Typically I import the PySide components as:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *
```

Notice the wildcard import statement. The problem is that the following throws an exception on import (`ImportError: No module named QtGui`):

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt.QtCore import *
from pyqtgraph.Qt.QtGui  import *
```

Is there a way around this? I would prefer not to have to go back into my code and replaces all the `self.clock_timer = QTimer()` with `self.clock_timer = QtCore.Timer()` statements.

**Short Cut:** If I could avoid going through `pyqtgraph` to import `QtCore` and `QtGui`, that would be even better. When I try to use do it (using the first import style) certain features (e.g. AutoPan) don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the beginning of your application to ensure that pyqtgraph pre-loads the pyside modules (and does whatever monkey-patching it needs to do):

```
import os

os.environ['PYQTGRAPH_QT_LIB'] = 'PySide'

from pyqtgraph import Qt
```

Now you can safely use your preferred imports, because `sys.modules` will already contain whatever (patched) modules pyqtgraph loaded:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
```

Comment: This looks promising! I will be able to try it out in a couple days, and then definitely come back to give you the check if it works.